# JPA with Pagination, Sorting and Specification along with distinct

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.1

I have tried to Use specification to to retrieve the data with various predicates everything works fine but I have sorting on some columns but I also want to use distinct to avoid duplicates here is the sample code I have which is causing an issue

here is a sample of the code

Transactions---this is the root/Parent

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy="transaction", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
private List<Documents> documents;

public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Transactions> transactionsRoot, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
    Path<PartnerPair> partnerPair = transactionsRoot.get("partnerPair");
    Path<SupplierProfile> supplierProfile = partnerPair.get("supplierProfile");
    Path<Documents> documents = transactionsRoot.join("documents");//one to many thats why the duplicate transaction records
    criteriaQuery.distinct(true);
}
```

and using pagebale through a repository

```
@Override
public Page<Transactions> getAllTransactionsListPageableFilters(Specification<Transactions> spec, Pageable pageable) {
    return transactionsRepository.findAll(spec, pageable);
}
```

is there a way to use use order by in terms of jpa at this instance I am using pageable to apply the columns to be sorted and it works but when I use criteriaQuery.distinct(true); the order by clause generated by jpa throws a SQL exception not a selected Expression..

any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to order by? What are `partnerPair` and `supplierProfile` for?

Comment: transactions have a one to many relationship on partner pair and supplierprofile has a many to one relationship on partner pair and I am trying to order by on a column in supplierprofile.

Comment: So you have a M:N relationship between transactions and supplierprofile. Well then you can't order on anything in `supplierProfile` since it won't be included in the select. I'm not even sure what that would suppose to mean. If at all you would need to order by something like `Max(supplierProfile.yourProp)` which I don't think you can express using Criteria API.

Comment: Yes I am trying to fetch now after doing some reading but it has its own set of problems transactionsRoot.fetch("documents", JoinType.LEFT);